# We’ve seen that $P (\emptyset) = \{\emptyset\}$, and $\{\emptyset\} = \emptyset$. What is $P (\{\emptyset\})$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We’ve seen that $P (\emptyset) = \{\emptyset\}$, and $\{\emptyset\} = \emptyset$. What is $P (\{\emptyset\})$?

Comment: We haven't seen that $\{\emptyset\} = \emptyset$, because it's not true.

Comment: No, $\{\varnothing\}\neq \varnothing$.

Comment: It is incorrect to say $\{\emptyset\} = \emptyset$. The set $\{ \emptyset\}$ has an element -- namely, $\emptyset$.

Comment: $\mathcal P(\{\emptyset\})=\{\emptyset,\,\{\emptyset\}\}$. Of course, $\emptyset\ne\{\emptyset\}$, since this goes both against the definition of $\emptyset$ and (if you want another argument) the axiom of regularity.

Comment: Not to mention Peano's theorem. If $\mathcal P(A)=A$, then $id_A$ would be a bijection $A\longleftrightarrow \mathcal P(A)$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\{\emptyset\}\neq\emptyset$$

The first has one element, the other none.

Anyway,

$$
P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}\\
P(\{\emptyset\})=P(P(\emptyset))=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}
$$

Comment: @probablyme Sure, done.